# different files in one folder as several data for opl model

Tags: file, directory, cplex, opl

I have an opl model in IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization studio. Every time in this model two CSV files are imported. There are 272 files, so this model should be run 136 times. Each time one CSV output is exported as a result. I need a solution to automatically read each of these two files each time, get the result and import the next two files until all the files are read. I added a picture of some of the files so you can see how they're named. How can I do this automatically. 
Also, the second part of my question is: for example one of my filename is: pmed1_DP=10_P=5_n=100 , I need to get the DP, P and n as inputs for my code. Is there any way to use the filename and get our required inputs?[filenames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltuDg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you can use a main to set a different output csv file. Let me give you a tiny example:

test.mod

```
tuple t
{
  string firstname;
  int number;
}

{t} s={<"Nicolas",2>,<"Alexander",3>};

string csvOutput=...;

execute
{
 var f=new IloOplOutputFile(csvOutput);
 for(var i in s)
 {
  f.writeln(i.firstname,";",i.number,";");
 }
f.close();
}
```

and then main.mod

```
{string} csvOutputs={"csv1.csv","csv2.csv"};

    main {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("test.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);



      for(var o in thisOplModel.csvOutputs)
      {
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);

      var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
      data2.csvOutput=o;
      opl.addDataSource(data2);
      opl.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {  
         opl.postProcess();
         writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
     opl.end();
    }  

    }
```

This will generate 2 csv files, csv1 and csv2.

For your second question you could either send parameters through a main like that or call oplrun many time and change the parameters with the `-D` parameter:

```
oplrun -DcsvOutput="csv3.csv" test.mod
```

This will generate `csv3.csv`.

Comment: I think I cannot explain my problem clearly. I have a set of files as an input, which is same as the added picture to my question, and each time two of these input (ex: pmed1_dp10_p5 & pmed1_dp1-_p5_d) are read and give me one specific out put. Each time I should add two files and get my output from the code. Because I have 136 files, I want to add them automatically. I mean instead of add each two of them every time, the code do it.

Comment: Hi, can t you have the list of input files in a string like {string} csvOutputs={"csv1.csv","csv2.csv"}; ? And then you ll do a flow control loop

Comment: The problem is that the filename is important because I want to use them as input. For example, I have pmed1_DP10_P5_N100 and DP,P and N, should be use as an input. Also there are 272 files and I cannot write this string to define them. I want some code to define the path of folder that includes all the files. Then read each two files each time, run the code and get the result. After that continue this loop until all the files will be read. Is it possible?

Comment: yes and for instance you could generate {string} csvOutputs={"csv1.csv","csv2.csv"}; with  a loop instead of giving all the values in extension

Comment: how can I give address of the folder that contains all the files?

Comment: If you turn csvOutputs into {string} csvOutputs={"c:\\temp\\csv1.csv","c:\\temp\\csv2.csv"}; then the output will be in the folder temp